# HD video problem with Ubuntu 14.04 on my HTPC

Tags: 14.04, video

720p and 1080p videos are jerky and not synchronized with the sound. Sound often stops after couple of seconds. Tried playing with VLC, SMplayer and Kodi Media Centre. Same thing on YouTube when playing HD videos.

HTPC is from 2008, until recently had Vista on it, but with Ubuntu as only OS works much better.

I have following configuration: MB Gigabyte MA78G-DS3H (full HD 1080p and Blu-ray play back), CPU AMD AM3 Athlon II X2 250 and Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780.

I am a complete beginner, searched internet regarding this topic and found couple of possible solutions, but nothing worked for me.

Will appreciate ideas what to try.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the proprietary drivers for your graphics card installed?

Comment: Wondering if your CPU could be the bottleneck, it performs rather poorly at CPU Benchmarks. Playing HD videos is hard work for most processors. Did they pay better in Vista? Also be sure to have all necessary codecs `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` should do the job.

Comment: @ Zacharee1 - no I don't have the proprietary drivers for my graphics card. I was looking into it, but couldn't find much as on AMD site it says that  my graphics card  is not included in the list of supported products for these specific distributions and AMD suggests upgrade to a current graphics card model.    Also, when I go on "Software and updates" it says that no additional drivers are available.

Comment: @theodorn I've already tried installing all codecs with that line you've written, but it didn't help. I have also a feeling that CPU might be the problem. This is not my original one, the first one I've installed had some issues, but it did play BlueRays and HD video without problems. This CPU was installed later. Wonder if overclocking of this CPU will help?

Comment: @Riz, I know next to nothing about overclocking, so I'm not qualified to answer about that. You can always ask a new question about overclocking, or search older questions and answers.

Comment: @theodorn Thanks anyway. Temperature of CPU is 73 to 74 degrees C when idle and temp of whole system 32. That CPU temperature seems way too much. When I find some time I will try to see what I can do to reduce that temp. Maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just un update to my querry regarding HD video playing problem and Ubuntu. Actually, problem had nothing to do with Linux, but with the broken support bracket for CPU cooler and fan. Due to broken bracket CPU cooler and fan weren't properly attached to CPU, so the CPU temperature was too high. It took me some time to find replacement bracket and now everything works fine.